# How can I do optimize multiple left joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, left-join

Can you help me get this query to work?

I have a log query that counts logged items (table: `log`) for each active user (table: `user`, status: `1` (for active)) by day (table: `calendar`, including days without rows.

The following query takes 10 minutes to run!  How can I run this in seconds rather than minutes?

```
SELECT
    c.day, COUNT(u.id) AS count
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN log l
    ON c.day = DATE_FORMAT(l.db_timestamp , '%Y-%m-%d')
LEFT JOIN user u
    ON l.user_id = u.id
    AND u.user_status_type_id = 1
WHERE
    c.day > '2012-12-01'
    AND c.day < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY
    c.day
```

Table structure:

```
calendar (~3,000 rows)
day
===============================
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
2012-01-03
...
2020-01-01


log (~30,000 rows)
id  user_id  db_timestamp
================================
1   1        2012-01-01 01:01:01
1   2        2012-01-01 01:01:01
1   1        2012-01-01 01:01:01

user (~3,000,000 rows)
id  user_status_type_id
================================
1   1
1   0
```

Result should look like this:

```
Sample Expected Results
day         count
=================
2012-12-01  1
2012-12-02  0
2012-12-03  4
...
2012-12-31  0
```

Unfortunately it takes forever to run.  What should I do next?

Comment: You showed the expected result - good. But what are you actually getting?

Comment: Or are you getting an error?

Comment: What's wrong with your query you posted? any errors? not the expected results? or do you want to generate the list of days if there are missing days not filled in the logs table? Please explain more so that we could help you.

Comment: where is this `day` in your table ?you said select c.day and i dont find `day` in your calender  table

Comment: Turns out it actually does work, it just took forever so I assumed I was doing something wrong.  Obviously I still am since I'm not searching through large datasets.  How can I optimize this?  Question updated.

Comment: @ryan can you update the question with resutl of EXPLAIN <your query>. look like some indexes need to create

Comment: I ended up using php to handle the zero rows.  Created an array of all dates and filled the array with a much simpler MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your selected columns you don't need any joins. use following sql

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(l.db_timestamp , '%Y-%m-%d') AS days, COUNT(l.id) AS COUNT 
FROM LOG l 
WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(l.db_timestamp , '%Y-%m-%d') > '2012-12-01' 
AND DATE_FORMAT(l.db_timestamp , '%Y-%m-%d') < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY days
```

for user wise count

use

```
GROUP BY days, l.user_id
```

Comment: @ryan then query can not be optimized in current structure as join columns are in different format. if you can make another column in log table that store only date (Y-m-d) then you can make join and create index on both the joined columns

Comment: I agree.  I ended up using php to generate the zero rows in an array and merging with the MySQL result based on a much simpler query with no joins.  Thanks again for your help but I just couldn't make it work in any acceptable time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::
USE `DATE()` WHILE JOINING

```
 SELECT
        c.day, COUNT(u.id) AS count
    FROM calendar c
    LEFT JOIN log l
        ON c.day = DATE(l.db_timestamp)
    LEFT JOIN user u
        ON l.user_id = u.id
        AND u.user_status_type_id = 1
    WHERE
        c.day between '2013-01-01'
 AND '2012-12-01'
        GROUP BY
        c.day
```